# Inclusion–exclusion principle for probability

Tags: calculus, probability, combinatorics, analysis, inclusion-exclusion

Inclusion–exclusion principle for probability is as follows: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

(1)How to use this principle to show that:
$$\sum_{i=1}^nP(\{x_i\}\subset X)+\sum_{1\leq i_1<i_2\leq n}P(\{x_{i_1}, x_{i_2}\}\subset X)+\dots+(-1)^{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^nP(\{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n\}\subset X)=?$$

(2)Also, What is the $1-P(\{x_1,\dots, x_n\}\subset X^c)?$

EDIT: What I want is that why $$1-\sum_{i=1}^nP(\{x_i\}\subset X)+\sum_{1\leq i_1<i_2\leq n}P(\{x_{i_1}, x_{i_2}\}\subset X)+\dots+(-1)^{n}\sum_{i=1}^n P(\{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n\}\subset X)=P(X\subset \Omega\setminus \{x_1,\dots, x_n\})$$
where $X=\{x_1, \dots, x_N\}$ of a finite set $\Omega$ with $|\Omega|\geq N$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  statement doesn't look right..It should read:

$1-P(${$x_1,...,x_n$}$\subset X^c)=\sum_k P${$x_k$}$\subset X)-\sum_{k\lt j}P(${$x_k,x_j$}$\subset X)+$etc.

The basic idea is the probability that all the subsets are in $X^C$ is $1-$ the probability that at least one subset is in $X$.  To calculate the later you add up the probabilities of one subset in $X$, but you need to subtract the probabilities that a pair of subsets is in $X$.    This results from a basic relation $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$

You then need to add back the probabilities for three subsets in $X$,etc.

Comment: That is to say that the complement for the event of all $n$ terms being excluded from $X$, is the event that *at least* one such term is included in $X$. $$\begin{align}1-\mathsf P\left(\{x_1,\ldots, x_n\}\subseteq X^\complement\right)&=1-\mathsf P\left(\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^n\{x_k\}\right)\subseteq X^\complement\right)\\[2ex]&=1-\mathsf P\left(\bigwedge_{k=1}^n \left(x_k\in X^\complement\right)\right)\\[1ex]&=\mathsf P\left(\bigvee_{k=1}^n\left(x_k\in X\right)\right)\end{align}$$

Comment: @herbsteinberg Well, what is the $\sum_{i=1}^nP(\{x_i\}\subset X)+\sum_{1\leq i_1<i_2\leq n}P(\{x_{i_1}, x_{i_2}\}\subset X)+\dots+(-1)^{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^nP(\{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n\}\subset X)=$?

Comment: @GrahamKemp But why $1-\sum_{i=1}^nP(\{x_i\}\subset X)+\sum_{1\leq i_1<i_2\leq n}P(\{x_{i_1}, x_{i_2}\}\subset X)+\dots+(-1)^{n}\sum_{i=1}^n P(\{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n\}\subset X)=P(X\subset \Omega\setminus \{x_1,\dots, x_n\})$

Comment: @herbsteinberg THANKS! Can you solve my edited question?

Comment: Notation is slightly confusing.  What is $\Omega$\{$x_1,....,x_n $}?